# Can't remove empty lines with sed regex

Tags: regex, sed, linefeed

I have a file like this:

```
2733617     3.00    3   3

2733617 E1b1    8.00    8   16
2733617 E1b1b1b 2.00    2   4

2733617 I1  294.00  296 590
2733617 I2  1.00    1   2

2733617 I2a1    2.00    2   4
```

`sed '/^$/d'` does not work for me. Outfile looks just like infile. It should remove empty lines.

Comment: check that there is no whitespace (including carriage returns) on those "empty" lines: `od -c filename`

Comment: Thank you for a command good to know. But there is only "\n" in empty lines.

Comment: `sed -n l file` will show what `sed` is seeing once it has removed the newlines.

Comment: Dollar signs in every empty line.

Comment: How strange.  Your command should work.  Could you post the output of `od -x`?

Answer (score 4):

to delete blank lines:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'
```

Comment: Glenn, excuse me. I'm total noob with `sed`. Could you explain me what does the `d` modifier do? I've googled it with no result :)

Comment: I wonder why if the very last line is empty, it does not get removed.

Comment: I'm editing in place btw.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the manual says that using ranges like `[!-~]` is not safe. However, just printing the lines that containing printable characters using `:print:` worked for me in the end:

```
sed -n '/[[:print:]]/p'
```

Comment: This is such an old question I have no idea where this mysterious file is today.

Answer (score 2):

Since there appear to be unknown non-printable characters in the "blank" lines, you could re-write your sed command to only display lines with printable characters in them:

```
sed -n '/[!-~]/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
 sed -n '/^./p'
```

which prints only lines which have at least one char at the beginning of the line. (BTW `sed '/^$/d'` works for me)

Comment: 1. You can also use `grep -v '^$'`
2. How do you use `sed` command? With UNIX pipes? (`cat file | sed ...`)? Maybe you're piping standard error output instead of standard output?

Comment: Grep gave me the same result. I "sed 'blahblah' file > newfile".