# Why do SED, GREP or AWK fail to remove blank lines from text files?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to remove blank lines from large text files. For some reason it seems that neither

```
sed "/^$/d" file.txt > trimmed.txt
```

nor

```
grep -v "^$" file.txt > trimmed.txt
```

nor

```
awk /./ file.txt > trimmed.txt
```

do anything. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the great comments by @fedorqui & @Sebastian Stigler the problem was quickly identified as DOS/Windows carriage returns (^M$) at the end of each line.

While I appreciate Sebatian's suggestion to reformat the files using `dos2unix` I would rather have a solution using the tools generally available in most linux distributions.

The solution that worked for me was an answer given by @Jeremy Stein to this question [[Can't remove empty lines with sed regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755692/cant-remove-empty-lines-with-sed-regex]):

```
sed -n '/[!-~]/p' file.txt > trimmed.txt
```

Comment: All the commands are fine. Could you indicate what is the output?

Comment: Well, neither of the commands removes the blank lines. However, file size seems to have nothing to do with it as a shortened version of the file in question (7kb) also has the blanks not removed.

Comment: Could it be that the files have some weird characters? Check it with `cat -vet file`. Could be that they come from Windows...

Comment: You're right, that's exactly the problem. A Carriage Return ^M$ has snuck in.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for the `-vet`; I see that `-A` is a new option which does all the three: show non-printing chars, line endings and tabs.

Comment: @legends2k that `-A` sounds good and easier to remember, thanks for reporting :)

Answer (score 4):

I just tried the commandos with a toy example and they work fine as long the `file.txt` was a file with **unix** newlines. If the file contains **windows** newlines then none of the commands were able to remove the blank lines.

You can use the `dos2unix` linux tool to convert the newlines in `file.txt` to unix newlines. If you need the output on a windows system then you can use `unix2dos` to convert `trimmed.txt` into a file with windows newlines.

Comment: I found another solution that actually suits me more (see Jeremy Stein's solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755692/cant-remove-empty-lines-with-sed-regex)